# Using Knockout.Js, how to do refresh the ul when new data is binding to li?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application, jquery-mobile-listview

Really i'm struggling with knockout js for couple of days. because I'm new to this technology. I'm unable to do refresh the ul when new data is binding to li. Given below is my code.

```
 <ul data-role="listview" id="ListSearch" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" >
         <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
              Criteria Selected
          </li>
          <!-- ko foreach: Contacts  -->
          <li data-theme="c">
              <a href="#page3" data-transition="slide" data-bind="attr: { title: ContactID }">
                  <span data-bind="text: FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' (' + Classification +':'+ Position+ ')'"></span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <!-- /ko -->
      </ul>
```

Jquery Ajax Call:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:50043/api/contacts/filter',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { ID: ClassificationPositionid },
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                 self.Contacts(result);
                $('#ListSearch').listview("refresh"); //throwing error.

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(".divLoading").hide();
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

ListSearch is the id of UL. If i given as like above then it throwing below error.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'
```

How to fix this error? Please help me where I made mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put given below code after error part in jquery ajax call,

```
     complete: function () {                 
                $('#ListSearch').listview('refresh');            
        }
```

**Important:
1) Don't load jquery after mobile plugin js
2)Don't load any jquery in body selection...
Please load the jquery(jquery.min.js,knockout,...) first and then load mobile plugin js**

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error here `$('#ListSearch').listview("refresh"); //throwing error.`, then simply it's a case that either:

- The jQuery Mobile ListView plugin is not loaded.
- The jQuery Mobile ListView plugin is loaded, but is not working.

Check which script files are loaded in your web page (browser dev tools via the F12 key, etc) to see which scripts are loaded. Maybe that jQuery file is missing?

EDIT:

In your position I would try the following - start a new project and only include jQuery and jQuery Mobile script files. Then Take the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#ListSearch').listview("refresh");
    });    
</script>
```

and see if the above fails. If it does, then 100% there is something wrong with the jQuery mobile script. Try getting that script file from somewhere else, like downloading it from the jQuery site and including it in your project.

Basically strip the code down to the minimal amount and see what works.

Comment: Hi Jason, <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>  <script src="https://codiqa.com/view/84ae65a7/js"></script> I'm loading these scripts in my page. Did I miss anything? Please tee=ll me

Comment: OK it looks like you are using jQuery mobile `.js` file in that list you posted. Next step, can you post the HTML where your <script> tags are located? It is possible that you are using the call to `.listview()` before the jQuery mobile `.js` file has been loaded.

Comment: I'm loading all the script tags inside the head element

Comment: Sorry, can you post the <head> section, specifically the <script> please?

Comment: I already posted the script tags of my head section. Please see above my message

Comment: Ahh sorry, yeah. To be honest, I'm not sure what's going on in that case. It looks like you are referencing the mobile script in the right order (jQuery first, then the jQuery mobile script file) so there's no problem there. Also it looks like the scripts are loaded before you try to use them in your code. It's not clear to me what's wrong here :( Sorry.

Comment: <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>
<script src="https://codiqa.com/view/84ae65a7/js"></script>.. these are the scripts loading in head element.